# Should an object know which 'arguments' it takes

Tags: java, constructor, default-value, bigdecimal

Consider you got a class with a constructor like the follwing

```
public class Clazz {

    protected BigDecimal bigDecimal;

    public Clazz(BigDecimal bigDecimal) {
        this.bigDecimal= bigDecimal;
    }

    public BigDecimal getBigDecimal() {
        return bigDecimal;
    }

}
```

Clazz takes only BigDecimals which are at least zero, that is

```
new Clazz(BigDecimalUtils.minZero(someBigDecimal));
```

Who is responsible to ensure that the class only gets instantiated with BigDecimals greater than zero? Is it the class itself (e.g. in the constructor)?

Comment: That's up to you and your design.  If you use a builder or factory pattern, those classes are good places to put logic like that.  If breaking the rule is a bug, then throw an exception in the constructor.  If breaking the rule might reasonably happen but the user needs to be notified and given another chance to enter a sensible value, then the code that validates user input is where the logic belongs.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about program design and belongs on http://programmers.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's whomever you want to be, generally I'd have something akin to:

```
public void setBigDecimal(BigDecimal aBigDecimal) {
     if (aBigDecimal.longValue() > 0l) {
            this.bigDecimal = aBigDecimal;
     } else { throw new IllegalArgumentException("positive numbers only!");
}
```

And then have your constructor leverage the above method:

```
public Clazz(BigDecimal b) {
    this.setBigDecimal(b);
}
```

I hope this is clear, do leave a comment if you have further questions.